# Bluetooth Low Energy Device Simulator/Emulator

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

For quite some time now, I have had a keen interest with the Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Protocol version 4.0 and how it works. I have developed an android application that would serve as a central device to the BLE peripheral device. The problem is the BLE device is not yet ready and I would like to know if there is a simulator or an emulator for BLE devices that can interact with my android application installed in my smartphone.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to do that without any specific additional HW is to use another Android or iOS mobile phone acting as a peripheral emulating the BLE device that's not ready yet. Thus, you'll be able to test your Central role Android app in a simple way.

All you have to do is download one of the following apps for example, set up your services and characteristics and start playing.

- [Android]: [nRF Connect for Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en)
- [iOS]: [nRF Connect for Mobile](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nrf-connect/id1054362403) or [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer/id557428110?mt=8)